# Box-shadow isn't working on any divs within my website. Does anyone have the slightest inclination to why? They are all in a container

Tags: css

Box-shadow isn't working on any divs within my website.  Does anyone have the slightest inclination to why?  Inset doesn't work either.  I have no idea what's going on :(.

Comment: Please put some code. Also, which browser are you using?

Comment: Your Question Means nothing, how are we supposed to know without seeing anything?

Comment: <div style="float: left; width: 33%; box-shadow:; box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px #000;"></div>    This is the simple code for the div.  Im using Dreamweaver and it's not working in any browser I preview it in or in designer view.

Comment: Your div is probably empty and thus is not visible. Put come content in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get rid of the empty `box-shadow:;` declaration .. the rest of your syntax looks proper from your comment.

If you're using older browsers then include the vendor prefixed versions:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px #000; /* Safari & Chrome */
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px #000; /* Firefox */
-o-box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px #000; /* Opera */
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px #000;
```

That should do the trick

Comment: you should also include AFTER Adrift's code: `box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px #000;`

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div style="float: left; width: 33%; box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px #000;"></div>
</body>
</html>                                                                        So this is the new code that still doesn't work.  I just bought and downloaded dreamweave 2 months ago so It should have the current browser views.  But the problem is also in designer view before I even preview it.  No div shows a box shadow when implemented.  However I can add and change borders easily...

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div
{
width:300px;
height:100px;
background-color:yellow;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>                                                                            There still is no box-shadow or border or anything but a yellow background inside the div :(

Comment: [This is your exact code minus the yellow background](http://jsfiddle.net/LdfPv/) .. it must be something else thats causing the problem.

Comment: yes....thanks for the quick responses.  Man I wish I used this site two months ago lol.  But sigh, no solution yet.  I wonder if there is something going on within dreamweaver?

Comment: thanks but for a newbie like me its beneficial.